# A basic differential inequality (in the proof of local uniqueness of ODE via fixed point method)

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Hi I am having trouble getting a differential inequality of the like
$$\frac{d}{dt}|y|^2\le 2K|y|^2$$
while reading the chapter on uniqueness of ODE.

Could anyone explain the first line of equation (5.2.10) as attached.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \lvert \mathbf{y} \rvert^2 = \mathbf{y}^*\mathbf{y} $, differentiating both sides gives
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \lvert \mathbf{y} \rvert^2 = \frac{d\mathbf{y}^*}{dt} \mathbf{y} + \mathbf{y}^* \frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dt}, $$
and interchanging the $^*$ and $d/dt$ on the first term,
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \lvert \mathbf{y} \rvert^2 = \left(\frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dt}\right)^* \mathbf{y} + \mathbf{y}^* \frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dt}, $$
and then use (5.2.8).

Comment: I just don't understand what is this * and why I need it.

Comment: what does * mean when you wrote $|y|^2=y^*y$?

Comment: $\mathbf{y}$ is in $\mathbb{C}^N$, so to get the absolute value, take the conjugate transpose: $ \lvert \mathbf{y} \rvert^2 = \sum_i \lvert y_i \rvert^2 = \sum_i y_i^* y_i $.

Comment: okay. So $y^*$ means $\bar{y}$ in ordinary notation for complex conjugate.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#Notation both are common.